# yii2 ckeditor Image source URL is missing

Tags: yii2, ckeditor

I'm using this ckeditor extension for yii2 https://packagist.org/packages/wadeshuler/yii2-ckeditor-cdn

I created directories backend/web/uploads/images and gave them rights 777

I configured backend/config/main.php like this

```
'modules' => [
        'ckeditor' => [
            'class' => 'wadeshuler\ckeditor\Module',    // required and dont change!!!

            'uploadDir' => '@app/web/uploads',    // must be file path (required when using filebrowser*BrowseUrl below)
            'uploadUrl' => '@web/uploads',        // must be valid URL (required when using filebrowser*BrowseUrl below)

            // These are basically passed to the `CKEDITOR.replace()`
            'widgetClientOptions' => [

                'filebrowserImageBrowseUrl' => '/ckeditor/default/image-browse',
                'filebrowserImageUploadUrl' => '/ckeditor/default/image-upload',
            ]
        ],

    ],
```

Put in the form

```
use wadeshuler\ckeditor\widgets\CKEditor;
<?= $form->field($model, 'body')->widget(CKEditor::className()) ?>
```

And when I upload an image and click "Send it to the server" it doesn't upload and when I click "ok" it says  Image source URL is missing.

Maybe someone has faced this problem before?
By the way, if I remove these lines

```
//'uploadDir' => '@app/web/uploads',    // must be file path (required when using filebrowser*BrowseUrl below)
        //'uploadUrl' => '@web/uploads',        // must be valid URL (required when using filebrowser*BrowseUrl below)
```

Nothing is changed. The same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

it's maybe a bit outdated, but who knows someone might stumble upon this same issue, although mine is a bit different in framework. i use codeigniter and trying to integrate it with ckeditor upload image plugin, but you should get the idea because the return value is the same for ckeditor.

[here](https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_(Uploader)/Custom_File_Browser) is a solution i found, refer to the link and see Example 3 section

which looks like this :

```
// Required: anonymous function reference number as explained above.
$funcNum = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'] ;
// Optional: instance name (might be used to load a specific configuration file or anything else).
$CKEditor = $_GET['CKEditor'] ;
// Optional: might be used to provide localized messages.
$langCode = $_GET['langCode'] ;

// Check the $_FILES array and save the file. Assign the correct path to a variable ($url).
$url = '/path/to/uploaded/file.ext';
// Usually you will only assign something here if the file could not be uploaded.
$message = '';

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, '$url', '$message');</script>";
```

you should note that `filebrowserUploadUrl` options must be pointed to your yii function which handle the uploaded image, which in this case looks like sample code above. and don't forget to add `uploadimage` and `filebrowser` on `extraPlugins` options.

hope that helps.